# Xdebug profiler output file

Tags: php, xdebug, kcachegrind, xdebug-profiler

X debug is returning output as parts instead of just one file. 
I am using ubuntu 16 and don't know why suddenly the output is  in several files. 
The problem that i have is that i cannot open this files in Kcachegrind as the output have different parts in separated files.
Anyone?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

With the default configuration xdebug creates one file per PID.

when you profile a website with ajax calls, the browser will make more than one request, and maybe these are processed by different PIDs/Instances of your webserver and so you get multiple files.

you could check your php.ini. there are multiple xdebug settings to control how the profiling data is stored. for example:

> **xdebug.profiler_aggregate:**
>   Type: integer, Default value: 0 When this setting is set to 1, a
>   single profiler file will be written for multiple requests. One can
>   surf to multiple pages or reload a page to get an average across all
>   requests. The file will be named .cachegrind.aggregate. You will need
>   to move this file to get another round of aggregate data.
>
> **xdebug.profiler_append:**
>   Type: integer, Default value: 0 When this setting is set to 1,
>   profiler files will not be overwritten when a new request would map to
>   the same file (depending on the xdebug.profiler_output_name setting.
>   Instead the file will be appended to with the new profile.
>
> **xdebug.profiler_output_name**
>   Type: string, Default value:
>   cachegrind.out.%p
>
> This setting determines the name of the file that is used to dump
>   traces into. The setting specifies the format with format specifiers,
>   very similar to sprintf() and strftime(). There are several format
>   specifiers that can be used to format the file name.

see more in the [xdebug documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler)

the other option is to use the [File/Add menu in KCachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/GUIMenu.html):

> Adds a profile data file to the current window. By this, you can force
>   multiple data files to be loaded into the same toplevel window even if
>   they are not from the same run as given by the profile data file
>   naming convention.